# Compilation errors since beta-5 on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

Since the beta-5 update, we're facing some compilation errors, but only when we deploy on the IIS server, not in VS 2015.
[image]

The odd thing is that we can't see the duplicate references which cause these errors. Any ideas ?

**Edit**: I deploy with the following configuration
[image]

Comment: did you deploy it with the beta5 runtime?

Comment: Yes (see my edited question)

Comment: Can you please share the project.json file?

Comment: it might help if you click the link to show raw compilation error details to find out more detail

Comment: Details are already shown.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution this morning. First I cleaned all my project.json, and removed unused dependencies. While cleaning, I removed "Microsoft.CSharp" and "SharpZipLib" dependencies, maybe one of them caused errors.